# How to increase range query performance on sql server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, lookup

I have a db where I have a little bit more than 2m rows. It has `startIpNum` and `endIpNum` columns(the ranges don't overlap). I am making some queries to that table:

table:

```
Id | startIpNum(Numeric(0,18)) | endIpNum(Numeric(0,18)) | locId
```

Query 1:

```
select locId from Blocks
where startIpNum <= 1550084098 and endIpNum >= 1550084098
```

Query 2(**added this query hoping for better results**):

```
select top 1 locId from Blocks
where endIpNum >= 1550084098
```

These queries take a reasonable time, no problems. But I need to get around 100 different rows each time I open a web page, and it tooks around 15 seconds which is possibly expected, but not desired.

I believe that by working with indexes I can increase that performence, so I've added 2 indexes, one to `start(asc)` one to `end(desc)` but performance is same.

What else can I do to achieve a better query performance?

**Update**

I have run the `create index` query you guys have proposed. No changes for now.

As requested I am including the sql query execution plans below(since I am not familiar with the execution plan thing I am only snipping screenshots from ssms, go ahead and ask if something else is required to answer my case):

Execution plan of Query1:

[image]

Execution plan of Query2:

[image]

Comment: `CREATE INDEX ix ON dbo.tbl (start, end) INCLUDE (id, value)`

Comment: For more detailed answers please provide your actual execution plan

Comment: SSMS can suggest index for you if it is missing - just include execution plan and click on show missing index details.

Comment: You could also have the table return only the required columns rather than all of them, that usually shaves time if you're not using all of them. It might also be worth casting the value explicitly as a `Numeric(0,18)` otherwise it might be trying to parse the value as an int and implicitly converting it to numeric. You might also see an improvement using `where start >= 123123123 AND end <= 123123123` since it wouldn't need to run the calculation twice on each row (though the execution plan should be converting it on the fly it might not be so being explicit again might help).

Comment: It is using the index so 15 seconds seems an extraordinary amount of time to run the query on a relatively small table. Can you run `set statistics io on` and `set statistics time on` before the `select` query and post the results (from  the "Messages" tab)?

Comment: @Tolga-Evcimen I have updated my answer to avoid the `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` but if this doesn't work then the stats would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned without an execution plan to look at this is slightly going slightly blind but the basic points are:

1) If the indexes are in place to support this query there is no point adding two. Only one of the indexes can be used. Therefore you need one index that contains both columns.

2) Bringing back "*" means that a key lookup will be inevitable as having used the index to get the rows it needs it will have to fetch the data not included in the index from the clustered index. Key lookups can get very expensive if you are bringing back large amounts of rows. If you can limit the columns you bring back then you can use an `INCLUDE` to avoid the key lookup. You don't need to include the primary key in this list as this is part of the index anyway.

Having said this your best option will be something like:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_range ON dbo.yourTable (start, end) INCLUDE (<list_of_columns_in_your_select)
```

Looking at your query plan it is also clear that a `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` is being performed on your parameters `@1` and `@2`. These should be avoided so do the following:

```
DECLARE @1numeric numeric(18, 0), 
        @2numeric numeric(18, 0)

SELECT @1numeric = CAST(@1 AS numeric(18, 0)),
       @2numeric = CAST(@2 AS numeric(18, 0))

SELECT locId FROM Blocks
WHERE startIpNum <= @1numeric and endIpNum >= @2numeric
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to explicitly cast the value compared to match the columns.

```
select * from that_table
where CAST(123123123 as Numeric(18,0)) between start and end
```

I assume sqlserver is losing the index seek due to the implicit cast.

Comment: This is incorrect. First of all not all functions within conditions lose sargability, you should read it up before you make false statements. Casting a scalar value has no influence on the sargability, rather does the condition matching. So is "BETWEEN" resolved to >= / <= by the optimizer and fully sargable.